# Solr sorting function fails with colon in field name

Tags: solr

I have a very strange problem with Solr sorting function. When I do a simple sort by field value, it works fine. Here the query that works:

```
q=ss_type:product_variant
sort=fs_field_master_product:field_price asc
```

However, when I do a sort by a sum of values it gives an error. The query:
q - the same

```
sort=sub(fs_field_master_product:field_price,10) asc
```

The error:

```
<lst name="error">
  <str name="msg">can not sort on a field which is neither indexed nor has doc values: sub(fs_field_master_product:field_price,10)</str>
  <int name="code">400</int>
</lst>
```

I couldn't find much about this kind of issues with sorting functions on Internet, any help is highly welcome!

ps. I was inclined to consider the colon in field's name to be the root of the problem, but Solr didn't fail in any other cases the field is used.

Comment: I have used sunspot solr(Rails gem). If you want to do a search against a newly added field, you need to index the database before.

Comment: The field is not a newly added. As I wrote Solr can sort by it, but it only fails to do that when a function is used in Solr sort. I appreciate your using of Rails, but how can it help with the issue described?

Comment: whats fs_field_master_product:field_price ? is it the field name with :

Comment: Doesn't it look like that? Especially when I explicitly wrote "I was inclined to consider the colon in field's name to be the root of the problem ..." ?

Comment: Missed the statement. : in the fields names also usually stands to alias so better not use them in the field names

Comment: This is not forbidden anywhere, and it works with simple sorting. So I'm inclined to consider that either a documentation or code bug of Solr.

Comment: yup .. there is no official documentation. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Solr-Field-name-restrictions-td3025233.html and a link in lucid had mentioned the same. you can debug your query and check what it interprets the colon to

Comment: Thanks, will try to add a clone field without colons (I need the field with colons anyway). It is impossible to debug a query that fails with an error.